# Error migrating MySQL database into Django. Unexpected host name

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to migrate a MySQL db into Django. I created a simple database when I followed a tutorial, but now I am trying to migrate my actual db into the project. I modified settings.py to look like this (changed the databases section):

```
"""
Django settings for tutorial project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '********'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'helloservice.apps.HelloServiceConfig',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'pulse',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'zzzz',
        'HOST':'yyyy-backend.cluster-cwtxulgbsb88.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT':'3306',

    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My error:

```
mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql://dev-backend.cluster-xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (74)")
```

Where the heck is it getting dev-backend.cluster as the database from?

My migrate command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: You'll want to change `SECRET_KEY` now.

Comment: haha oops....thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check for settings downstream of that `DATABASES` assignment. A common pattern in Django projects is a layout like this:

```
# In settings.py, declare all the base values
DATABASES = { ... }
INSTALLED_APPS = [ ... ]

# Import other settings based on environment
if os.environ.get("environ") != "production":
    from .devel import *
```

For better or worse this pattern or variations thereof are commonplace. You likely have an import under a conditional later in the file.

Comment: I updated my code to include my entire settings.py. Are there any other files I should check? I didn't see anything odd in settings.py as far as references to other files went

Comment: @Rilcon42 Can you ping the DB from where you're running Django? Is there a `CNAME` or redirect setup?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem.

> if yyyy-backend.cluster-cwtxulgbsb88.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com  is
>   correct??  
> **can name resolve**?

You might want to use its 
**IP address** for connecting instead.

> Because Usually the case when name resolving doesn't work on the host.